# How to get green/red terminals under OpenBSD?

Tags: prompt, openbsd, ksh

For linux machines I can use:

```
# vi ~/.bashrc # red/green terminal colors regarding exit code

export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`
if [[ \$? = "0" ]];
then echo "\\[\\033[0;32m\\]";
else echo "\\[\\033[0;31m\\]";
fi`[\u@\h \w]\[\e[m\] "'
export PS1
```

to get green terminal when exit code is 0, and get red prompt when exit code is not 0.

How can I do this under OpenBSD? (the default ksh)

(I was trying to do it, but with no luck - using ssh to connect to the OpenBSD machine from my notebook - ubuntu/gnome-terminal. )

Comment: Typically, `PS1` does not need to be exported since I don't know of any programs besides interactive shells that use it, and interactive shells get their value of `PS1` from the relevant `rc` file already.  The reason I mention this is environment variables take up space in `ARG_MAX` which means you generally don't want a huge environment, or else you will run into "argument list too long" errors more frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is only `bash` has `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  Try this instead:

```
PS1='\[$(if (($?)); then tput setaf 1; else tput setaf 2; fi)\]'\
'[\u@\h \w]\['"$(tput sgr0)"'\]'
```

<sup>¹ Caveat: I haven't tested this on `ksh`, but it avoids `PROMPT_COMMAND` and works in `bash`.</sup>

<sup>² `tput` uses your system's `terminfo` databases.  This is generally more portable and maintainable than hard-coding escape sequences, provided terminfo is installed correctly.</sup>

Comment: tput: Unknown terminfo capability "2" when I log in via console:P

Comment: You need to set `TERM` to something that supports the `setaf` attribute, e.g. `TERM=xterm`.  (I think the error indicates `tput` doesn't know that `setaf` takes a numeric argument, since it's not set for your current terminal.)

Answer (score 4):

Each shell has its own way of expanding the prompt. OpenBSD's ksh is pdksh. See its prompt settings in the [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ksh&sektion=1), under the `PS1` parameter.

The way ksh works is that it performs parameter substitution, command substitution and arithmetic substitution (all the `$` expansions) on the value of `PS1` before printing the prompt. So you set `PS1` once and for all, but the value is regenerated each time. (You can do that in bash too, if you put `shopt -s promptvars` in your `.bashrc`.)

OpenBSD's ksh supports backslash escapes similar to bash. With other versions of ksh, you'd need to translate the bash prompt escape sequences into `$` substitutions as well.

```
PS1='$(if (($? == 0)); then print -n "\\033[32m"; else print -n "\\033[31m"; fi)'
PS1="$PS1"'[\u@\h \w]'$(print '\033')'[0m '
```

The simple translation above has a few defects:

- It forks a process each time, to analyze `$?`. There is a way to avoid this, but it's hackish in ksh88.
- It causes redrawing bugs, because of the zero-width control sequences. This can be avoided with the gross hack documented in the manual.

Here's some more complex code that uses arithmetic to avoid spawning a subshell and takes care of delimiting non-printable sequences.

```
escape=$(print '\033')
ctrla=$(print '\001')
PS1=$(print '\001\015')
PS1=$PS1$ctrla$escape'[$(($? ? 31 : 32))m'$ctrla
PS1=$PS1'[\u@\h \w]'
PS1=$PS1$ctrla$escape'[0m'$ctrla' '
```